# How to get the minimum date of same column in DB2

Tags: db2

[Need to get order qty of the minimum ADATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6LUS.png)

Im using below query and getting 12 records. Now I want to select orderqty of minimum ADATE which is 06-NOV-2018(2018-11-06).
For every customer(will get multiple records), i need to get the Order_Qty of minimum ADATE column.

```
select
   Customer ,
   OrderID ,
   LocationID ,   
   Order_Qty,Sent_date ,ADATE
   from
   (
      select
      OrderID ,
      LocationID ,
      Sent_date ,
      Order_Qty ,
      Customer ,
      TimeStampA
      from ARC_TBL
   )
   obn
   inner join
   (
      select
      ADATE ,TimeStampA
      from trackTBL snt
   )snt
   on obn.TimeStampA = snt.TimeStampA
    where Customer='ABC' and OrderID='XYZ100' and Sent_date='2018-11-18' and LocationID='250';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT QTY, ADATE
  FROM table
 ORDER BY ADATE 
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Explain your question in more detail and you will get better answers.

Comment: For every customer(will get multiple records), i need to get the Order_Qty of minimum ADATE column.
select Customer,OrderID,LocationID,Order_Qty,Sent_date,ADATE from (select OrderID, LocationID,Sent_date,Order_Qty,Customer,TimeStampA from ARC_TBL) obn  inner join( select  ADATE ,TimeStampA  from trackTBL snt
 )snt on obn.TimeStampA = snt.TimeStampA where Customer='ABC' and OrderID='XYZ100' and Sent_date='2018-11-18' and LocationID='250';